# How do I use properly CASE..WHEN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, switch-statement, case

Here is a demo query, notice it is very simple, Fetches only where base_price is 0,
And still, it chooses the condition 3:

```
SELECT
   CASE course_enrollment_settings.base_price
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0      THEN 1
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price<101      THEN 2
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price>100 AND   
                      course_enrollment_settings.base_price<201 THEN 3
        ELSE 6
   END AS 'calc_base_price',
   course_enrollment_settings.base_price
FROM
    course_enrollment_settings
WHERE course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0
```

`base_price` is `decimal(8,0)`

When run this on my DB, I get:

> 3 0
>   3 0
>   3 0
>   3 0
>   3 0

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Remove the `course_enrollment_settings.base_price` immediately after `CASE`:

```
SELECT
   CASE
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0      THEN 1
    ...
    END
```

`CASE` has two different forms, as detailed in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html). Here, you want the second form since you're using *search conditions*.

Comment: If you wanted to sort by the values, what would the order by clause look like since there is not a column alias?

Answer (score 46):

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statements
    [WHEN when_value THEN statements]
    ELSE statements
END
```

Or:

```
CASE
WHEN <search_condition> THEN statements
[WHEN <search_condition> THEN statements] 
ELSE statements
END
```

here CASE is an expression  in 2nd scenario  search_condition will evaluate and if no search_condition is equal then execute else

```
SELECT
   CASE course_enrollment_settings.base_price
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0      THEN 1
```

should be

```
SELECT
   CASE 
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0      THEN 1
```

Comment: what are the brackets ? `[` and `]`

Comment: @Shafizadeh those imply that you could add more when statements after the first.

Answer (score 17):

`CASE course_enrollment_settings.base_price` is wrong here, it should be just `CASE`

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0      THEN 1 
WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price<101      THEN 2 
WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price>100 AND    
                  course_enrollment_settings.base_price<201 THEN 3 
    ELSE 6 
END AS 'calc_base_price', 
course_enrollment_settings.base_price 
FROM 
  course_enrollment_settings 
WHERE course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0
```

Some explanations. Your original query will be executed as :

```
SELECT 
CASE 0
WHEN 0=0 THEN 1 -- condition evaluates to 1, then 0 (from CASE 0)compares to 1 - false
WHEN 0<1 THEN 2 -- condition evaluates to 1,then 0 (from CASE 0)compares to 1 - false
WHEN 0>100 and 0<201 THEN 3 -- evaluates to 0 ,then 0 (from CASE 0)compares to 0 - true
ELSE 6, ...
```

it's why you always get 3

Comment: "No need for" is imprecise. It's "you _should not_ have".

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbi: agree; I changed it and added some explanations

Comment: I was getting an error when I added a column alias `AS 'calc_base_price`.
I solved it by adding parenthesis around the whole `(CASE ... END)`

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT
   CASE 
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0      THEN 1
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price>0 AND  
         course_enrollment_settings.base_price<=100     THEN 2
    WHEN course_enrollment_settings.base_price>100 AND   
         course_enrollment_settings.base_price<201      THEN 3
        ELSE 6
   END AS 'calc_base_price',
   course_enrollment_settings.base_price
FROM
    course_enrollment_settings
WHERE course_enrollment_settings.base_price = 0
```

Comment: Changed ur conditions a little.. Added <=100 instead of <101

Answer (score 6):

There are [two variants of `CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html), and you're not using the one that you think you are.

#### What you're doing

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Each condition is loosely equivalent to a `if (case_value == when_value)` (pseudo-code).

However, you've put an entire condition as `when_value`, leading to something like:

```
if (case_value == (case_value > 100))
```

Now, `(case_value > 100)` evaluates to `FALSE`, and is the only one of your conditions to do so. So, now you have:

```
if (case_value == FALSE)
```

`FALSE` converts to `0` and, through the resulting full expression `if (case_value == 0)` you can now see why the third condition fires.

#### What you're supposed to do

Drop the first `course_enrollment_settings` so that there's no `case_value`, causing MySQL to know that you intend to use the second variant of `CASE`:

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Now you can provide your full conditionals as `search_condition`.

**Also, please read the documentation for features that you use.**

Comment: What I needed -- this was clear enough that I could actually adapt it to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of it is that you're stating the value you're selecting after `CASE`, and then using `WHEN x = y` syntax afterward, which is a combination of two different methods of using `CASE`.  It should either be

```
CASE X
  WHEN a THEN ...
  WHEN b THEN ...
```

or

```
CASE
  WHEN x = a THEN ...
  WHEN x = b THEN ...
```