# Issue with CASE expression in MySQL: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Ok, so I am writing SQL code in MySQL to get customer names from 2 different tables and display them for the user.

I have a CASE setup in my SQL, however when I run it I get the message

> "Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)."

The syntax is pulling information from an "account" table, displaying rows that are not present in a "transaction" table, and needs to sort them by account holder type, either business or individual. And either display the individual's first and last name (if the account is held by an individual) or the business name (if held by a business).

Here is my syntax giving the error:

```
use bank;

select acct.account_id as "Account ID", 
case (select cust_id from account
  where acct.cust_id = ind.cust_id)
  when acct.cust_id = ind.cust_id 
    then (select fname, ' ', lname from individual ind)
  when businessacct.cust_id = bus.cust_id 
    then (select name from business bus)
  end cust_type,
acct.cust_id as "Customer ID", 
acct.last_activity_date as "Date last active", 
acct.avail_balance as "Available Balance", 
(select concat(fname, ' ', lname) 
  from employee 
  where emp_id = acct.open_emp_id) as 'Opening Employee'
from account acct, 
  individual ind, 
  business bus
where acct.account_id not in (select account_id from transaction)
order by acct.cust_id;
```

I realize no one can really run this without the tables I have, but can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588015/how-do-i-use-properly-case-when-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few issues in your query; you're not using the case expression correct and there are serious problems with the joins. Even if you corrected the problems in the case expression the query would most likely not function as intended as you don't join the tables in any meaningful way.

Since you didn't share any schema or sample data this is just a guess as to what the query probably should look like:

```
select 
    acct.account_id as "Account ID", 
    case 
       when acct.cust_id = ind.cust_id then concat(ind.fname, ' ', ind.lname) 
       when acct.cust_id = bus.cust_id then bus.name 
    end cust_type,
    acct.cust_id as "Customer ID", 
    acct.last_activity_date as "Date last active", 
    acct.avail_balance as "Available Balance", 
    concat(emp.fname, ' ', emp.lname)  as 'Opening Employee'
from account acct 
join employee emp on emp.emp_id = acct.open_emp_id
left join individual ind on acct.cust_id = ind.cust_id
left join business bus on acct.cust_id = bus.cust_id 
where acct.account_id not in (select account_id from transaction)
order by acct.cust_id;
```

You could probably replace the whole case expression with this:

```
coalesce(bus.name, concat(ind.fname, ' ', ind.lname)) cust_type,
```

which would select the bus.name is there is one (meaning it's a business) or use the values from individual instead.