# How to set default values when left joining an empty subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the number of sales associated with each of my sellers. I've managed to do this for overall sales by joining to a subquery as below:

```
SELECT seller.*, COALESCE(apc,0) AS total_sales
FROM seller
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT seller_id, COUNT(seller_id) AS apc
    FROM purchase
    GROUP BY seller_id
) AS ap ON ap.seller_id = seller.id
```

However, I also want to calculate the number of sales over the last three months, so I extended the query to this:

```
SELECT seller.*, COALESCE(apc,0) AS total_sales, COALESCE(rpc,0) AS recent_sales
FROM seller
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT seller_id, COUNT(seller_id) AS apc
    FROM purchase
    GROUP BY seller_id
) AS ap ON ap.seller_id = seller.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT seller_id, COUNT(seller_id) AS rpc
    FROM purchase
    GROUP BY seller_id
    WHERE purchase.time_created > [date three months ago]
) AS rp ON rp.seller_id = seller.id
```

When I run this query, I get the error `Unknown column 'rpc'` which I believe is happening because the rp subquery is coming back empty as my current data set has no sales in the past three months.

I've used the `COALESCE` function to handle a null value in a field, but this second subquery doesn't even seem to create a table to contain any null fields.

Is there a way to set some default values for this?

Comment: You may case when in mysql, Some thing like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588015/how-do-i-use-properly-case-when-in-mysql

Comment: @SelvakumarPonnusamy I'm not sure how that would help me. What would my case condition be to check if the subquery had any records?