# Sum in a Select with where or IF SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a `SELECT` and I want to 'SUM' different rows if the NIF are equal to an other nif and the contract are the same to other and the product is 100

```
SELECT 
 NIF, 
 CONTRACT, 
 PRODUCT, 
 SUM(SALDO) when PRODUCT=100 
 DATE
from TABLE_AAA
```

And then I would like to convert as a chart.

```
NIF     CONTRACT    PRODUCT     SALDO   DATE
1       1001        100           1     27/04/2016
1       1001        100           1     27/04/2016
1       1003        100           2     27/04/2016
1       1003        100           2     27/04/2016
1       1001        102           1     27/04/2016
2       1001        200           5     27/04/2016
2       1001        200           1     27/04/2016

NIF     CONTRACT    PRODUCT     SALDO   DATE
1       1001        100         2       27/04/2016
1       1003        100         4       27/04/2016
1       1001        102         1       27/04/2016
2       1001        200         5       27/04/2016
2       1001        200         1       27/04/2016
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Not as a comment, we can't read that. Edit your question instead,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the combination of two queries actually:

1. the aggregated rows for product 100
2. the unaltered records for the other products

So write two queries and combine the two with `UNION ALL`:

```
select nif, contract, product, sum(saldo) as saldo, max(date) as date
from table_aaa
where product = 100
group by nif, contract, product
union all
select nif, contract, product, saldo, date
from table_aaa
where product <> 100
order by nif, contract, product, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `WHERE` not when, and include your other parameter in the `WHERE` clause, also you need a `GROUP BY`. Without sample data and expected output this is what I presume you are after.

```
SELECT 
NIF, 
CONTRACT, 
PRODUCT, 
SUM(SALDO) AS SUMSALDO,
DATE
FROM TABLE_AAA
WHERE PRODUCT = 100
AND CONTRACT = NIF
GROUP BY NIF, CONTRACT, PRODUCT, DATE
```

Ok maybe you mean this:

```
SELECT 
NIF, 
CONTRACT, 
PRODUCT, 
SUM(CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 100 AND CONTRACT = NIF THEN SALDO ELSE 0 END) AS SUMSALDO,
DATE
FROM TABLE_AAA
GROUP BY NIF, CONTRACT, PRODUCT, DATE
```

Comment: @AleixCaminal added second answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the sum function of SQL.
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;

In your case,

```
SELECT NIF, CONTRACT, PRODUCT, SUM(SALDO) FROM Table_AAA WHERE PRODUCT = 100 AND NIF = CONTRACT;
```

I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
NIF, 
CONTRACT, 
PRODUCT, 
CASE 
    WHEN (NIF = CONTRACT AND PRODUCT=100)
    THEN
        SUM(SALDO)
    WHEN(otherCondition)
    THEN
        SUM(otherSum)
    ELSE 
        NULL
END
DATE from TABLE_AAA
```

You can find more information about CASE in sql there [How do I use properly CASE..WHEN in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588015/how-do-i-use-properly-case-when-in-mysql) or there https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

In case that you would like to sum, rows that satisfy the same condition and you have more than one condition, I think you can you the following query:

```
SELECT 
 NIF, 
 CONTRACT, 
 PRODUCT, 
 SUM( case when NIF=CONTRACT AND PRODUCT=100 THEN SALDO ELSE 0 END ) SUM_PROD_100 ,
 "DATE"
from TABLE_AAA
GROUP BY NIF, CONTRACT,PRODUCT, "DATE"
```

You can use the same logic as in column "SUM_PROD_100" to sum other rows that satisfy a different condition.