# Display icon based on database value

Tags: php, mysql, database, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple table view using Bootstrap. I intend to display icons based on the entry of a database field (e.g., the database field is '0', the icon shall be glyphicon-remove, when it is '1' it shall be glyphicon-ok). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, make an array in php with icon0 (text) on position [0], icon1 (text) on position [1], etc

Comment: easy if/else statement

Comment: Yes. Share what you've tried and give some hints about the things not working yet, then we can help you find the error

Comment: Yes, you can even use CASE WHEN THEN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588015/how-do-i-use-properly-case-when-in-mysql

Comment: I've tried this https://pastebin.com/ac0jKAG1

Comment: That looks fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: It worked after i added a <span> tag. Thank you all